# xscreensaver: authentication via PAM time out

Tags: pam, desktop, screen-lock, xscreensaver

When I lock the screen via LXDE desktop environment, there is a time bar running. After it runs out, it displays a message:

```
xscreensaver: (system time) authentication via PAM time out.
```

I don't know if this is an error message, even if it is not, I don't really like it. Question, how to get rid of it properly(meaning I still need to lock the screen)?

Comment: The message just says that the time bar ran out. It isn't an error, in the sense that the system is reacting normally to what the user did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) is just a method of authentication on for systems that Linux users. It timing out just means the screen saver didn't authenticate within the given time.

It's noting to be concerned about.

Comment: except that "how to make it go away" would be nice.